# Vertical align headers with image

Tags: html, css, liquid

I have the following liquid code:

```
<body>
  <table data-mce-fragment="1" width="100%" height="100%">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td
          data-mce-fragment="1"
          style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top"
        >{{ 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0556/5258/1539/files/windows-logo.png'| img_tag: 'Windows Compatible Operating Systems' }} &nbsp;<b>Windows Compatible Operating Systems</b><br><br>
        {{ product.metafields.custom.windows_compatible_operating_systems_3_0 }}
        </td>
        
        <td
          data-mce-fragment="1"
          style="width: 50%; vertical-align: top"
        >{{ 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0556/5258/1539/files/mac-logo.png?v=1707807667'| img_tag: 'Mac Compatible Operating Systems' }} &nbsp;<b>Mac Compatible Operating Systems</b><br><br>
        {{ product.metafields.custom.mac_compatible_operating_systems_3_0 }}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

How can I get each the windows and mac headers vertically aligned center with their corresponding image?

It is currently being outputted like attached screenshot.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcoeq.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) using the `<>` icon.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: Apply `vertical-align: middle;` to the images ...?

Comment: Hey, you need to vertically align the image, not the ```<td>``` element.